# Replacing the file name which comes with # (Hash) using sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I facing some problem with replace the file name mixed with #

```
Ex:- #test#123
```

i have maintaining the report file like report.csv, Im using the bash script to summarize my report.
by default my report.csv file comes with all extension type as a default template.

Inside my report.csv
   DATE-COPY COPY_STATUS NO_TXT NO_ERR NO_SQL
if my copy success i will replace using sed from COPY_STATUS to COPY_SUCCESS
if its normal file(/home/user/text123.txt) is copied i dont have problem with replacing path

```
sed 1s#NO_TXT#/home/user/text123.txt# -i report.csv
```

after that my csv file will look 
     DATE-COPY COPY_SUCCESS /home/user/text123.txt NO_ERR NO_SQL

if i have # hashmixed file 
example

```
   sed 1s#NO_TXT#/home/user/#text#123.txt# -i report.csv
```

i get like below error and unable to replace hash files with full path

```
    sed: -e expression #1, char 44: unknown option to `s'
```

Comment: Quote your sed string and use `|` as your sed separator instead of `#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sed can use a number of characters for its separator. Most commonly a `/` is used, however for files it's handy to use another character such as `#`, as you have done. In your instance, the simplest approach would be to use another separator such as `|`, but ensure you quote your sed string:

```
sed '1s|NO_TXT|/home/user/#text#123.txt|' -i report.csv
```

Or if you are passing in a variable, use double quotes:

```
sed "1s|NO_TXT|/home/user/$file|" -i report.csv
```

Comment: Thanks, Actually i will get the path using as variable which assigned ex.(path=/home/user/#text#123.txt) if i use       sed '1s|NO_TXT|$path|' -i report.csv i just got $path instead full path in my report file.

Comment: Use double quotes. Then the variables will expand.

Comment: Sorry, still i get "$path" in my report file.  sed -i '3s|NO_TXT|"$path"|'   report.csv

Comment: I updated my answer to fit your use case. Please give that a whack. Thanks.